# What is the function of this =COUNTIF(Data!B:B,Data!B:B&"") Excel Formula?

Tags: mysql, excel

I'm trying to convert excel formula to mysql syntax. I can't understand what is the function of this formula:

```
=IF(G1="ALL",SUMPRODUCT((Data!I:I>=Dashboard!C4)*(Data!I:I<=Dashboard!C5)*(Data!P:P="ON-TIME")*(Data!B:B<>"")/
COUNTIF(Data!B:B,Data!B:B&"")),
SUMPRODUCT((Data!D:D=G1)*(Data!I:I>=Dashboard!C4)*(Data!I:I<=Dashboard!C5)*(Data!P:P="ON-TIME")*(Data!B:B<>"")/
COUNTIF(Data!B:B,Data!B:B&"")))
```

Can someone explain what is the function of this COUNTIF(Data!B:B,Data!B:B&"")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Excel **COUNTIF**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34):
>   Syntax: `=COUNTIF (range, criteria)`
>   Description: `COUNTIF` is a function to count cells that meet a single criteria. COUNTIF can be used to count cells with dates, numbers, and text that match specific criteria. The COUNTIF function supports logical operators (>,,=) and wildcards (*,?) for partial matching.

Range is obvious, but the criteria includes two Excel hacks that can be a bit obscure:

1. `&` before a cell reference will construct a text string.

   - see [COUNTIFS with wildcard characters](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/07/10/excel-countifs-multiple-criteria/#COUNTIFS-wildcard-characters) (its still not 100% clear)
   - *{range}&""* means to include empty cells as a value in the computation, because normally empty cells will be skipped automatically.
2. Criteria with a range will cause a spill range evaluation

   - Note: I can't find a good reference on this...
   - Visually in excel this formula will be repeated for each cell in the range

`COUNTIF(Data!B:B,Data!B:B&"")` is saying:
Count the values in the range `Data!B:B` that match this cell's value, if this cell is empty, count all the empty cells in the range.

- But do this for every cell in the range as well, returning a matrix of values for each cell in the range, this is the spill range bit.

It might be easier to demonstrate it, see this example:
- Range: A1:B3
- Criteria: Count all matches of the same value in the range, for each cell
- Column E shows the results of the individual formula displayed in column D
- Column I shows the results of the individual formula displayed in column H
- D5 shows the single formula that has a spill range the size of the source range matrix
- For comparison, H5 the formula that has a spill range the size of the source range matrix

[image: Excel Countif Spill Range]

> Note the results in J5, without the `&""` the blank cell will not be included in the count results.

In this example we can see how you could extrapolate the formula into individual cells, meaning you would have to enter the formula multiple times, but when you try to set that formula in the first cell (D1) and use the formula drag caret drag that formula to the other cells, it will also transpose the ranges, which is not what you want, see this:

[image: Excel Countif formula drag]

Especially when your range is large, putting a range in the criteria, creating a spill range means that we only have to define the formula once and excel will effectively transform that into individual formulas for each cell in the range.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Really appreciated :)